# Subset using a series of number in a loop

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have to subset a file for different numbers in a column and create several files in output. I am trying to do this in a loop but some how the iterator is not working.

## Input (tab-separated fields)

```
abc 1  
aaa 1  
ccc 1  
asd 2  
sad 2  
aaf 3
```

## Output

**File1:**

```
abc 1  
aaa 1  
ccc 1
```

**File2:**

```
asd 2  
sad 2
```

**File3:**

```
aaf 3
```

My test is this but it outputs only empty files:

```
for i in $(seq 1 3); do awk -F "\t" '{$2 == $i}' input  > cluster.$i.txt; done
```

Comment: Are your input fields tab-separated? (Your `awk` code seems to expect them to be.)

Comment: yes they are tab separated, have you tried if it works for you?

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't test without knowing the input format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code is failing is that you're trying to use a shell variable `$i` inside an `awk` script but doing so incorrectly. Text inside single quotes `'...'` is treated literally by the shell so the `$i` is seen as two characters rather than the value of the shell variable `$i`. You're also trying to perform a comparison as an action (which means there's no implied action to print the line).

You could pass the value in to `awk`

```
awk -F $'\t' -v i="$i" '$2 == i' input > "cluster.$i.txt"
```

Or you could treat each line on its own merit and avoid `awk` entirely:

```
while read field index
do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$field" "$index" >> "cluster.$index.txt"
done < input
```

Or you could use `awk` for much the same thing:

```
awk '{ fname = "cluster." $2 ".txt"; print > fname }' input
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation @roaima

Comment: There are buggy `awk` implementations out there that don't allow you to redirect to an expression like that. The solution is simply to calculate the output filename first, and then redirect to that: `fname = "cluster." $2 ".txt"; print >fname`.

Comment: I checked the size of all the output files and also the contents. They match with the expected size and names inside (if this is the problem). I have used the 1st solution proposed `awk -F $'\t' -v i="$i" '$2 == i' input > "cluster.$i.txt"`

Comment: @Kusalanander I haven't come across such implementations myself but am happy to accept your advice. Thank you.

Comment: @Kusalananda those implementations aren't buggy, it's just that an unparenthesized expression on the right side of input or output redirection is undefined behavior per POSIX. So `print > "foo" 7` can be interpreted by any given awk as `(print > "foo") (7)` (a syntax error) or `print > ("foo" 7)` (the presumably desired behavior and still be POSIX compliant. So you can put an expression on the right side of in/out redirection with `>` or `<` but put it in parens if you want it to work in all awks.

Comment: @roaima that last awk script is the right approach but as written it'll fail with a "too many open files" error message once you get past about a dozen output file names unless you're using gawk which handles that internally. You can solve the problem for all awks with `awk '$2!=prev{ close(fname); prev=$2; fname = "cluster." $2 ".txt"} {print > fname }' input` for sorted input or `awk '{ fname = "cluster." $2 ".txt"; print >> fname; close(fname) }' input` otherwise.

Comment: @fusion.slope the solution you've chosen involving a shell loop will be orders of magnitude slower than the final 1-call-to-awk solution above.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for both points. I don't tend to use these parts of `awk` often so I've not hit these issues. In these Q&A situations it's often a fine line between simply testing that the sample data works and trying to test exhaustively and completely. Too much complexity hides the (theoretical) solution behind (necessary) implementation. Too little and it fails for real-world data sets. Here, the OP had hard-coded just three output files.

Answer (score 2):

`$i` inside the awk expression doesn't refer to shell variable `i`. You can pass the variable in on the command line using `-v i="$i"` and refer to it as plain `i`.

Also `{....}` defines an *action* not a *pattern*; you appear to want to perform the default action (`print`) when the pattern `$2 == i` is true. So

```
for i in $(seq 1 3); do 
  awk -F "\t" -v i="$i" '$2 == i' 
input  > cluster.$i.txt; done
```

However, rather than calling awk once for every index, you might consider doing something like

```
awk -F "\t" '{print > "cluster" $2 ".txt"}' input
```

which uses the input's `$2` directly to construct the output file name.

Note that unless you are specifically trying to prevent field-splitting on space characters, you can probably drop the `-F "\t"` and allow awk to split on the default whitespace separators.

Comment: See my comment about too many open files at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533423/subset-using-a-series-of-number-in-a-loop#comment987478_533432